# How can I calculate this summation? $\sum_{x=60}^{100} {100\choose x} $?

Tags: summation

How can I calculate this summation?
$$\sum_{x=60}^{100} {100\choose x} $$ ?

I don't have idea how to calculate it, I tried to arrive at a probability expression of a random variable that is binomial ($Bin(n,p)$) but But I did not succeed.

Comment: ${n \choose k}= {n \choose n-k}$ can be useful ...

Comment: "Compute" or "estimate"?

Comment: @Did Calculate accurately, without approximation.

Comment: Then the answer is $$36057011612866492098338762600$$ Sorry but what is the point?

Comment: @Did the point is to know how to calculate it, it's so clear from my question.. Your answer don't answered about my question because that I don't asked for the result, but, I asked the way to calculate it..

Comment: [How to compute the exact value of this sum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+binomial(100,k)+from+k%3D60+to+k%3D100). Again: what is the point?

Comment: I guess most of us implicitly assume the point is to calculate it more efficiently then naively adding up 41 terms.

Comment: @Did Still, you don't explained how can I calculate it, you gave me the final result for this summation, and it's not my question.

Comment: @Sil Allowing one substraction, one can go down to 11 terms, each rather large, but apart from that...

Comment: @Did I asks for trick for how can I calculate it..

Comment: AskMath: "you [did not] explain[] how can I calculate it, you gave me the final result for this summation" Wrong, I gave you the link showing you how I computed the value of the sum.

Comment: AskMath "I asks for trick for how can I calculate it.." What makes you think there are such tricks?

Comment: @Did Gut feeling

Comment: AskMath: "Gut feeling". Proven wrong, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The following is standard:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk=2^n.$$

Comment: Can you explain how to continue?

Comment: @AskMath $$\sum_{k=60}^{100}=\sum_{k=0}^{100}-\sum_{k=0}^{59}$$

Comment: @DonAntonio I tried it, but then in $\sum^{59}_{k=0}$ it's not in the format that he writed.. it's will be $\sum^{59}_{k=0} {100 \choose k}$ and not  $\sum^{59}_{k=0} {59 \choose k}$ and

Comment: "Hint" about what?

Comment: Hint about subtracting two such expressions, as @DonAntonio made explicit in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no way to avoid summing at least few of these (rather large) binomial coefficients, but at least you can limit number of those if you utilize hint below.

**Hint:**

$$
\sum_{x=0}^{100} {100\choose x} = 2\sum_{x=50}^{100} {100\choose x}-\binom{100}{50}
$$

Comment: "Hint" about what?

Comment: @Did I don't understand your comment. Hint how to go about calculating the sum in question.

Comment: @Sil How can you continue from this point?

Comment: OK, how do you suggest to use this "hint" to compute the value of the sum?

Comment: By noticing the rhs is similar to sum in question, and leads to evaluating only 10 terms, instead of 40, maybe?

Comment: Yeah, 11 terms actually, allowing for a substraction, as I mention in a comment on main. **However**, each term being rather large, one also must be able to sum these...

Comment: @Did I see your point, updated answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sum_{x=0}^{100} {100 \choose x} = {(2)}^{100} $$
And using the fact that $ {n \choose r} = {n \choose n-r} $ it can be shown that $$ \sum_{x=50}^{100} {100 \choose x} = {(2)}^{99} $$ 
So $$ \sum_{x=60}^{100} {100 \choose x} = {(2)}^{99} - \sum_{x=50}^{59} {100 \choose x} $$